# Is there a simple way to know how many rectangles in some shaped grid there are if one knows the number of their corner points?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, rectangles

Is there a simple way to know how many rectangles in **some shaped** grid there are if one knows the number of their corner points?

I.e. if I have some grid (possibly non-equilateral, other than rectangular shape as well) and I know all the corner points of individual rectangles in the grid, but not the rectangles themselves (i.e. I don't have "list of type: rectangle", I have for "a list of points"), then can I calculate how many rectangles there are?

**Particularly**, I want to know the area of a polygon by intersecting it with a grid of rectangles.

Comment: if im understanding this correctly, you want the number of rectangles in an $n\times m$ grid?

Comment: does the configuration $:\ :\ :$ contain two or three rectangles?

Comment: @CSquared Yes but the grid is not necessarily rectangular shaped. I know all the corner points of the rectangles.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Two.

Comment: why does that configuration only contain two rectangles?

Comment: @CSquared Well maybe it's domain-specific. In my application that would have two rectangles, the left and the right. How can I specify this in the question? Non-intersecting?

Comment: Are you trying to generalize [Pick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @player3236 Seems like that. The main issue seems to be that I find that it's trivial if one traverses through each rectangle and sums the areas of found rectangles. But this implementation is not very elegant. Thus I was interested about some possible quicker solution. –